# Azure Application Insights Query for Message Exceptions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azureportal

I have an API log, I want to know which of the exceptions message in the log appears frequently (something like group by exception error message)

```
traces
| where severityLevel == 4
| summarize count() by exceptions
```

Comment: Normally exceptions go to the `exceptions` table. If in your case they are logged to the `traces` table the summarize by the `message` field.

Comment: because the message field contains unique error Id, it doesn't group them together even though they have same error message and just different Id

Comment: Can you post an example message field? Is the error is always at the same location? Could we parse the message to strip the is?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

In application insights, I check exceptions using below kql query and I summarized it based on method:

```
exceptions 
 | summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 30d), method
```

[image]

Here you can summarize by any other property(or a part of property using where property contains ).

**EDIT:**

You can use below query:

```
traces
|where message contains "Input string was not in correct format bla bla .."
| summarize count()
```

**EDIT2:**

```
traces
| where message contains "Initializing Warmup Extension." or message contains "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to python. Skipping W"
|summarize count() by message
```

[image]

Here you can x or y or z like the above example.

Comment: I want to be able to group them by the error messages i.e "Input string was not in correct format bla bla ..."

Comment: You can use this :

```traces
|where message contains "Input string was not in correct format bla bla .."
| summarize count()``` Here message is the property name , if your exception comes in x, place x in place of message, simple.

Comment: I get I can do this but that would mean that I have to do this for every single error messages instead of writing a query to group the errors

Comment: Then you have to use exceptions table for that case not the traces as the message is not same every time

Comment: you can use ```traces
| where message conatins "error"
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 30d), message``` here error is word which would appear in exception messages, you can use another similar thing in exceptions , otherwise use exceptions table.

Comment: Or you can use **OR** Operator https://i.imgur.com/p86efYX.png

Comment: Check **edit2** , I guess this solves all your issues.